# Advanced Custom Field Background Conflict

Tags: php, css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Advanced Custom Field to build reusable modules and using flexible content to build a parallax module.

**Module Template**

```
<style>
    .parallax-bg {
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    .hero-child {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        z-index: 0;
        height:100%;
        background-image:url("<?php the_sub_field('parallax_image_sm'); ?>");

    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
        .parallax-bg {
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: top center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            position: relative;
         }
         .hero-child {
             background-image:url("<?php the_sub_field('parallax_image_lrg'); ?>");
         }
    }


</style>



<section class="parallax-bg <?php the_sub_field('add_class'); ?>" style="overflow:hidden;"> 
    <div class="hero-child" data-bottom-top="background-position:50% 100px;" data-top-bottom="background-position:50% -100px;"></div>
    <div class="row">
            <div class="parallax-content">
            <?php the_sub_field('parallax_content'); ?>
        </div><!!--end parallax content -->
    </div>
</section>
```

When I use the same module on the page, the same background image shows up for the same sections. I am trying to find a way around this. I was thinking of using a GUID but was hoping there was a more simple solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the code provided is being repeated multiple times, and so the final set of  content is what will display for all of them, because each  tag uses the same class names, so the last one on the page will override all other styles.

You would need to implement some sort of counter to give each  its own unique styles. Maybe something like this:

Before your loop/repeater, add this:

```
<?php $i = 0; ?>
```

Then, just as your loop/repeater starts, add this:

```
<?php $i++; ?>
```

Then, make the following changes to your code:

```
<style>
.parallax-bg<?php echo $i; ?> {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.hero-child<?php echo $i; ?> {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 0;
    height:100%;
    background-image:url("<?php the_sub_field('parallax_image_sm'); ?>");

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .parallax-bg<?php echo $i; ?> {
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: top center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        position: relative;
     }
     .hero-child<?php echo $i; ?> {
         background-image:url("<?php the_sub_field('parallax_image_lrg'); ?>");
     }
}


</style>
<section class="parallax-bg<?php echo $i; ?> <?php the_sub_field('add_class'); ?>" style="overflow:hidden;"> 
<div class="hero-child<?php echo $i; ?>" data-bottom-top="background-position:50% 100px;" data-top-bottom="background-position:50% -100px;"></div>
<div class="row">
        <div class="parallax-content">
        <?php the_sub_field('parallax_content'); ?>
    </div><!!--end parallax content -->
</div>
```

So this will output your html like this for the first instance of your loop:

```
<style>
.parallax-bg1 {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.hero-child1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 0;
    height:100%;
    background-image:url("<?php the_sub_field('parallax_image_sm'); ?>");

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .parallax-bg1 {
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: top center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        position: relative;
     }
     .hero-child1 {
         background-image:url("<?php the_sub_field('parallax_image_lrg'); ?>");
     }
}


</style>
<section class="parallax-bg1 <?php the_sub_field('add_class'); ?>" style="overflow:hidden;"> 
<div class="hero-child1" data-bottom-top="background-position:50% 100px;" data-top-bottom="background-position:50% -100px;"></div>
<div class="row">
        <div class="parallax-content">
        <?php the_sub_field('parallax_content'); ?>
    </div><!!--end parallax content -->
</div>
```

Giving your a  with the class **parallax-bg1** and a  with the class **hero-child1**. Your second instance would end with a 2 instead.

I'd suggest putting all of the common styles inside a CSS files, and then just have your background-image styles inside your loop, as the rest of the styles probably remain universal between all of the  and  elements.